# How do I consume a file resource as a string, in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#

When I add a txt file as a resource to a project, how can I then consume the contents of that resource as a string?

The closest I've been able to get is by using the Resource Manager, to pull an unmanaged stream. However, this throws a null error:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
    Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream(
        "TestFile.txt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an Embedded Resource (as opposed to a Resource)?  If it is, you'd want to use `GetManifestResourceStream`

Comment: Additional to stephens comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Comment: I just added a text file named `test.txt` as a resource, and it added it as a `String` to `Properties.Resources.test`. So I'm wondering what you did differently.. I just went to the project properties, then `Resources`->`Add Resource`->`Add Existing File`. After that I don't have to "consume the contents as a string", it *is* a string already.

Comment: This is a resource I added through the project's Properties / Resources tab. It is not currently added to the project as an embedded resource, although I could do that.

Comment: In that case I assume you can just do, `Console.WriteLine(Properties.Resources.TestFile)` and it will write out the whole file, no `StreamReader` needed. According to my test, you already have a `string` object that is the whole file and the object resides under `Properties.Resources.TestFile`. I thought that was clear from my first comment, my mistake. I also assume this "embedded resource" stuff *would* mean that you need to `StreamReader` it because then it's an actual file, not a `string`.

Comment: @Quantic thank you, that pushed me to the answer.

Comment: This is not a coding question about Visual Studio. Dont tag a tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this too:

```
var myAss = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var mytxtFileResource = "Namespace.Project.MyTxtFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(mytxtFileResource))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: using System.Reflection;

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do it like that for text files
Just write it like this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(lines);
file.Close();
```

---

and read it like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.

System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}

file.Close();
```